# MVC routing: change views for all controllers in a directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a subdirectory in Controllers named Admin, which contains several controllers.

Is there a way to change the route so that I can put all the views in "/Admin" for every controller in the Admin directory? Or do I need to map a route for every single controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Areas of ASP.Net MVC 2.0, in which case you need not map route for every controller.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/aspnet-mvc-2-areas